# How to add roles/group while adding a user in wso2 is 5.9.0 using scim2 apis?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I am trying to create a user using this api-https://localhost:9443/scim2/Users

How do i add this user to a created group? Can you please Provide the payload

My Payload-

```
{
    "schemas": ["urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User"],
    "name": {
        "familyName": "jackson",
        "givenName": "kim"
    },
    "userName": "test2",
    "password": "abc123",
    "postalcode":"56789",
    "profileUrl":"gmail.com",
    "emails": [
        {
            "type":"default",
            "value":"a@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "value": "kim.jackson@gmail.com",
            "type": "home"
        },
        {
            "value": "kim_j@wso2.com",
            "type": "work"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following will add the user "Kris" with SCIM id "81cbba1b-c259-485d-8ba4-79afb03e5bd1" to the group using "Patch" operation.

```
{
   "schemas":[
      "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp"
   ],
   "Operations":[
      {
         "op":"add",
         "value":{
            "members":[
               {
                  "display":"Kris",
                  "$ref":"https://localhost:9443/scim2/Users/81cbba1b-c259-485d-8ba4-79afb03e5bd1",
                  "value":"81cbba1b-c259-485d-8ba4-79afb03e5bd1"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Bellow is the full CURL command. You can always refer [1] for API information.

```
curl -v -k --user admin:admin -X PATCH -d '{"schemas":["urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp"],"Operations":[{"op":"add","value":{"members":[{"display": "Kris","$ref":"https://localhost:9443/scim2/Users/81cbba1b-c259-485d-8ba4-79afb03e5bd1","value": "81cbba1b-c259-485d-8ba4-79afb03e5bd1"}]}}]}' --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://localhost:9443/scim2/Groups/a43fe003-d90d-43ca-ae38-d2332ecc0f36
```

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/apidocs/SCIM2-endpoints/#!/operations#GroupsEndpoint#patchGroup

Comment: Sir is it possible to add roles while creating the users or will i have to add them everytime into the group after a user is created????????

Comment: Yes you can. By defining them in the "groups" attribute. 
https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7643#section-4.1.1

Comment: Sir i am trying to send this -

Comment: {
    "schemas": ["urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User"],
    "name": {
        "familyName": "jackson",
        "givenName": "kim"
    },
    "userName": "test12345",
    "password": "abc123",
    "postalcode":"56789",
    "profileUrl":"gmail.com",
    "roles": [
        {
            "type": "default",
            "value": "s2ic"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: It is still getting added in internal/everyone

Comment: Seems I read the spec wrong. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7643#section-4.1.2 says groups are readonly attribute. So unfortunately you can't add groups while creating the user. The other way is possible (Add users while creating groups) but this isn't.